# Evaluate $\lim_{(x,y,z) \rightarrow (0,0,0)} \frac{xy+4yz^2+5xz^2}{x^2+y^2+z^4}$?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Can somebody help me to evaluate
$$\lim_{(x,y,z) \rightarrow (0,0,0)} \frac{xy+4yz^2+5xz^2}{x^2+y^2+z^4}?$$

The first thing I tried to do was set $x=y=0$ and evaluate the limit, and I got that the limit of the function was $0$. I did the same thing for $x=z=0$ and $y=z=0$. So, I was pretty confident the limit was $0$. My online homework said that was incorrect. I think set $x=y$, set $z=0$ and took the limit, which was $\frac{1}{2}$.

So basically, I found a direction in which to take the limit that didn't agree with the other directions. Can somebody tell me more about how I should think about this? How would I know to set $x=y$ in the future? I felt like it was a lucky guess. Thanks!

Comment: Heurisctically, setting $z=0$ was a way of isolating the lowest degree term in the numerator. From there, choosing a $2$D path was easy. This won't always be the case though because it depends on the denominator. Sometimes isolating the second lowest degree term would be the path, etc.

Comment: The cautious way, which will tell you exactly what to do, is to call the denominator a constraint, then use Lagrange Multipliers to find maximum  and minimum of the numerator, subject to the constraint. That is, when is the gradient of the numerator an exact multiple of the gradient of the denominator.  Or, when is the ordinary cross product of the two gradients the zero vector? Let me think of an easy three variable example  that still requires Lagrange...

Comment: Yet another case where people who actually know what's going on only comment, but the users who want points write the first thing that comes to their mind as an answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't know it before.

Just try to get different resultats.

Another way.

For $(x,y,z)=(\epsilon,\epsilon,\epsilon)$ and $\epsilon\rightarrow0$ we obtain:
$$\frac{xy+4yz^2+5xz^4}{x^2+y^2+z^4}=\frac{1+4\epsilon+5\epsilon^3}{2+\epsilon^2}\rightarrow\frac{1}{2}.$$
But for $(x,y,z)=(2\epsilon,\epsilon,\epsilon)$ and $\epsilon\rightarrow0$ we obtain:
$$\frac{xy+4yz^2+5xz^4}{x^2+y^2+z^4}=\frac{2+4\epsilon+10\epsilon^3}{5+\epsilon^2}\rightarrow\frac{2}{5}.$$

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, by $z^2=w$ and spherical coordinates we obtain

$$\frac{xy+4yz^2+5xz^2}{x^2+y^2+z^4}=\frac{xy+4yw+5xw}{x^2+y^2+w^2}=f(\theta,\phi)$$

and therefore the limit doesn't exist.

Comment: $f(\theta,\phi)?$

Comment: @mjw I mean some function of the angles since $\rho$ cancels out.

Comment: okay, I get it.  A bit subtle but nice approach!

Comment: @mjw Thanks! We can also determine explicitely $f(\theta,\phi)$ but it is not so important for the conclusion.